# Test case for loading progress - Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a page developed with angular 1.5, it shows a loading progress while initial API call, I want to write test case for this. I'm using a variable `this.loaded` to handle the loading progress. Initially `this.loaded = false` and once everything is loaded it will be `this.loaded =true`, but when I write test case `this.loaded` is alway **true** since the test case is checking final value of the variable. How I can slow down the flow and check the progress is getting triggered or not using Jasmine test?

**HTML:**

```
<loading-directive is-loaded='$ctrl.loaded'>
    DOM to show after loaded
</loading-directive>
```

**JS:**

```
function componentCtrl (someFactory) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.loaded = false;

    someFactory.someMethod().then(function () {
        _this.loaded = false;
    });
}
```

I want to check the _this.loaded = false before the call happens.

Comment: It seems to me that you are creating whatever triggers the load on the beforeEach method. Maybe you should consider move this to your test block (it). Can you share your code?

Comment: @PedroVaz, I have updated some code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check the value of _this.loaded before the factory call. A work-around that you could do to achive that is to mock the factory call in a way that it doesn't change the _this.loaded and you can still check it is false. I will create an example that might give you an insight. I hope it helps:

```
describe('MyController Spec', function() {

  // Load module
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

  it('Check if loaded is false if factory call does not change its value', inject(function($controller) {
        //setup
        spyOn(someFactory, 'someMethod').and.callFake(function() {
              //create a promise mock that will not execute the code that 
              //changes _this.loaded
              var uselessPromiseMock = {
                      then: function() {}
              };
              return uselessPromiseMock;
        });

        //action
        var myController = $controller("componentCtrl");

        //assert
        expect(myController.loaded).toBeFalsy();
  }));

  it('Check if loaded is true after a normal controller initialization',  inject(function($controller) {
        //action
        var myController = $controller("componentCtrl");

        //assert
        expect(myController.loaded).toBeTruthy();
  }));

});
```

PS: I'm assuming you mistyped and the callback that you pass to the factory call changes _this.loaded to true :)